# Renaming for .net core application in diffrent efpt.renaming.json files

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

We create a new .net core application. For this application we have our database which is very big. So we have to use database first. For that we are using the powertools. Because our tables and fields always have prefixes like `tbl` we use the efpt.renaming.json file. This looks like this: https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/blob/master/src/GUI/EFCorePowerTools/efpt.renaming.json

This works good. But because our database is very big this file gets huge. So is there a possibility to split the file? Like a partial class in programming. To split the renaming in two files. Or can I create multiple renaming files?